# Can a vampire use Bloodheal to cure a human disease?

Tags: world-of-darkness, vampire-the-masquerade, disease

Not too long ago I pondered whether a vampire would suffer being a carrier of a disease that is spread via blood, for example, HIV, upon feeding on an ill kine.

Now, he seems a bit remorseful that he's got Vampire AIDS and wonders whether blood healing will rid him of it, and if it's applicable to "human" diseases in general.

I'm talking about the V20 version.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

#### No, standard healing does not do this.

A vampire can't exactly *catch* a disease in the same way that a mortal can. Even if a vampire drinks infected blood they themselves don't become ill. Instead they potentially become *carriers* for the disease, and could pass it on when feeding due to things like bacteria or viruses being on their fangs which are then stabbed into others. The most direct analogy I can think of is it's like passing around dirty needles-- once contaminated, they can spread disease to anyone that uses them.

The standard healing mechanic for non-aggravated damage (spend a blood point, restore a hit box) doesn't work for this. The diseases don't actually damage the vampire at all, and so there is nothing to heal. Vampires do not generally have the ability to disinfect or purify things and so they can't just clean the blood. It's not clear how long a disease can persist this way (an undead body isn't the ideal environment for infectious bacteria and viruses).

---

#### In V20 this is difficult to do, but possible.

I had to dig deep to find an explicit way to cure a disease! It's inconvenient and requires access to some unusual Disciplines.

First, you will need someone with both Obeah and Valeren at two dots each. That person can then take the combination Discipline *Auguring the Sickness* (*Lore of the Bloodlines*, page 81). Using this is a Perception + Medicine roll at difficulty 7 to learn detailed information about their injuries or illnesses.

Second, that person can then use the three dot Obeah power *Corpore Sano*. Normally this would not cure a disease, even if identified by using *Sense Vitality*, because *Corpore Sano* can only restore health levels (like using blood to heal does). But *Auguring the Sickness* states

> Additionally, once
> augured, the vampire may use Corpore Sano (V20, p. 469)
> to cure the disease outright, at a difficulty determined by
> the commonality and virulence of the disease (difficulty 5
> for the common cold, difficulty 7 for most forms of herpes
> or chicken pox, or difficulty 9 for Ebola or HIV).

So there you go! As far as I know there's no reason someone couldn't use these powers on themselves. So if he's a vampire with the right Disciplines, or knows one who does, it's possible. The right Disciplines is tough. Obeah is in-clan only for Salubri while Valeren is in clan only for Salubri *antitribu*.

---

Before I could check my books I had mistakenly suggested the Tremere Thaumaturgy ritual *Purity of Flesh*. This ritual explicitly does *not* cure blood diseases.

The ritual I was thinking of is from *Blood Magic: Secrets of Thaumaturgy*, page 94, and is the level 3 Thaumaturgy ritual *Cleansing of the Flesh*. This is, however, a Revised Edition source, so it doesn't apply to V20.

That ritual cures the vampire of any drug addictions or non-supernatural diseases. It also requires the subject to lose all but one blood point at a rate of 2 points per hour, so it's still largely a vampire-only option.

Comment: I was a little unclear with my meaning of "cured", I guess! What I meant is "what would be the required procedure to stop being a carrier", which you also seemingly described. Thanks!